# Variable = true even though the if-statement is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I am making a notification system userscript.. Basically what it does, is that it sends a GET request to a site with a .txt file on it. The file outputs like this:

```
12345|User notification
all|Everyone will see this
```

`12345` is the user's ID and `all` is just set to display the message to everyone. When I write the user's ID (like 12345), it will send a notification to the specific user with the ID 12345, and if I write "all" it will send a notification to everyone.

PROBLEM: I have a dismiss button for each of the notifications (because both can be shown at the same time), but when I dismiss both, then send a new notification, both notifications will be shown, even though I dismissed one of them. Here's my code:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://website.com/notification.txt",
    ignoreCache: false,
    onload: function(response){
        res = trim(response.responseText);
        array = res.split("\n");

        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array2 = array[i].split("|");

            if(array2[0] == uid) {
                userMessage = array2[1];
            }
            if(array2[0] == "all") {
                allMessage = array2[1];
            }
        }

        if(typeof userMessage !== 'undefined'){
            if(GM_getValue("userMessage") != userMessage) {  
                GM_setValue("userMessage", userMessage);
                GM_setValue("userDismiss", false);
            }
        }

        if(typeof allMessage !== 'undefined'){
            if(GM_getValue("allMessage") != allMessage) {
                GM_setValue("allMessage", allMessage);
                GM_setValue("allDismiss", false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Look at these two if-statements:

```
if(array2[0] == uid) {

if(array2[0] == "all") {
```

That checks if the user ID equals the user's uid (user ID) or if it says `all`. Then look at these:

```
if(GM_getValue("userMessage") != userMessage) { 

if(GM_getValue("allMessage") != allMessage) {
```

Those check if the stored message (inside GM_getValue) from previous notifications does not equal the new data it just received. If it's the same, it shouldn't continue, however, if only ONE of the notifications are different, it will say both if-statements are true and then continue. Even though `GM_getValue("userMessage") equals userMessage`, it will still continue to proceed the if-statement, even though it says `!=`.

Also, I tried console.log() on the userMessage, allMessage, and the GM_getValue() ones, and if I try to add a notification for all, it will say userMessage is the same as the GM_getValue("userMessage). So something is wrong with those if-statements, but I don't know what.

Any help would be appreciated. I am pretty stuck here, so please help me out. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to properly scope a few variables here, like (`allMessage`, `userMessage`, and a few others).  I think once you scope `allMessage` and `userMessage` properly you will be good!

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://website.com/notification.txt",
  ignoreCache: false,
  onload: function(response){
    var res = trim(response.responseText);
    var array = res.split("\n");
    var array2 = [];
    var allMessage, userMessage;

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array2 = array[i].split("|");

        if(array2[0] == uid) {
            userMessage = array2[1];
        }
        if(array2[0] == "all") {
            allMessage = array2[1];
        }
    }

    if(typeof userMessage !== 'undefined'){
        if(GM_getValue("userMessage") != userMessage) {  
            GM_setValue("userMessage", userMessage);
            GM_setValue("userDismiss", false);
        }
    }

    if(typeof allMessage !== 'undefined'){
        if(GM_getValue("allMessage") != allMessage) {
            GM_setValue("allMessage", allMessage);
            GM_setValue("allDismiss", false);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

This way old results won't affect the new results.